# "New answer posted" notification for answerers

Tags: feature-request, answers, notifications

I posted an answer to this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/184098/evaluation-of-sum-limits-n-0-infty-left-operatornamesin-frac-pi2/184193#184193) on August 19, and 4 days later a great [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/185128/11069) has been posted, which I noticed by sheer luck.

I wish I was notified when the answer was posted. Please consider implementing this feature.

Comment: Every question has its RSS feed, to which a link is provided at the bottom of the page.

Comment: @LVK Thanks for bringing it to my attention. I would consider it a work-around though, because it requires some manual manipulations.

Comment: Just to clarify: What you suggest to is to implement such notifications for **all** questions you have answered or only for **some** of them (which you would choose in some way)? The latter is not that different from favorites, in my opinion. See also the comments and answers here:
[Mark problems as “notify me if answer is posted”?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4867/mark-problems-as-notify-me-if-answer-is-posted).

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thanks for the very relevant link. I would like to get notifications for **all** questions I answered. If I made it favorite, which I now did, would the site notify my of the new answers, question edits, etc? Or is it just for bookmarking to check back often. If so, I would rather use the RSS feed.

Comment: No, marking it as favorite does not send you a notification. But I usually check my favorites at least once a week and I see which questions had some activity - they are highlighted. (But you don't see what kind of activity was on the question - I think that it is highlighted even in the cases that new comments appear there or when the questions was edited.) I think details about this can be found at meta.SO, perhaps this question could be relevant: [What does highlighting mean on the profile's “Favorites” tab?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114274/). (cont...)

Comment: (cont...) Since I have only few favorites, I don't mind when I see highlighted question and then I find out that it was only because some minor edit or new comment. If number of favorites is vast (e.g. if I had all questions I've answered there), this would be really annoying. **TL;DR:** You don't get notification in inbox, you have to check favorites tab. Questions are highlighted for several other reasons, not only new answers.

Comment: I agree this would be a useful feature to have.

Comment: Recently a new feature related to this was implemented, see: [The Follow Questions and Answers feature is now live across the Network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661) and [A way to “watch” questions?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6994#31406)